# How can I add the number up in the list using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm very new to the python scene and I try to do some simple code but got stuck. This is the question

```
data = [6,1,4,7,3,8,5,9,1,3,4]
```

and I want to add up all the number to become 51 (6+1+4+7+3+8+5+9+1+3+4)
This is what I do so far,

```
unknow = 0
if x in data:
```

And I can't progress anymore. Please help.

Comment: Just do `sum(data)`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way will be to `sum(data)`, resulting in 51, but if you want a more orthodox way then it will be

```
data = [6,1,4,7,3,8,5,9,1,3,4]
data_sum = 0
for item in data:
    data_sum+=item

print(data_sum)
```

Comment: It's sure is open to discussion, but `sum` is more short and easy to understand in code, especially for the novice, for not resulting any more flood I'll just keep it be :)